# How to architect an Ember.js application

Tags: ember.js

It's been difficult to keep up with the evolution of Ember JS as its approached (and reached!) version 1.0.0. Tutorials and documentation have come and gone, leading to a lot of confusion about best practices and the intent of the original developers.

My question is exactly that: What are the best practices for Ember JS? Are there any updated tutorials or working samples showing how Ember JS is intended to be used? Code samples would be great!

Thanks to everyone, especially the Ember JS devs!

Comment: This question ranks on the top for a Google search for 'EmberJS tutorial', but it doesn't really answer that question.  This is really a question about 2 links on the internet. Would you consider changing this question to fit the title?  I think the best answer would be one that actually took someone through the process of creating an application with EmberJS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an important project that both new and veteran Ember.js developers should take advantage of:

[***Ember-CLI***](http://www.ember-cli.com)

While it does require some comfort level with the command line, you can generate a modern Ember project with community recommended best practices in a matter of seconds.

While it is beneficial to setup an Ember.js project the hard way as in Mike Grassotti's answer, you should not be doing that for production code.  Especially when we have such a powerful and easy to use project like `Ember-CLI` to show us the Yehuda approved [happy path](http://media4.popsugar-assets.com/files/2014/08/07/827/n/1922283/de1315c2e39c1511_Animations-500-days-of-summer-8231477-400-225KzX1kN.xxxlarge/i/Which-accurately-captures-how-feels-have-gotten-some.gif).

Comment: Thanks Matt! I've made this the accepted answer to direct traffic to Ember-CLI.

Comment: Just started using Ember for the first time a couple of days ago, and the Ember-CLI is quite easy to get started with and use. Only downside is that it does introduce a lot of complexity you might not want/need (although complexity that can be overlooked, if you're a trusting sort of individual). Bower and JSHint and Ember-CLI and Travis CI and EditorConfig and Git config files, along with other things like Broccoli for assets and PhantomJS for testing...

Comment: Fair point @JKillian.  I know there is a concern about Ember's learning curve, for those reasons.  While Ember-cli does introduce some complexity (Ember-data & Broccoli), it removes significant confusion around vendor requirements and structuring your project. So there's a grain of salt.

Comment: Fully agree with the Ember CLI happy path!  Mike Grassotti's quickstart guide below would be the perfect "next step" if it wasn't so... outdated. For those looking to build Ember 2.0 apps, the best thing, as far as best practices go, is to make sure you understand the core concepts: models, routes, services, components, etc.

Ember docs are a great resource, but since I haven't come across a single updated guide connecting all concepts (much less with a sample app) I decided to write this up: http://emberigniter.com/5-essential-ember-2.0-concepts/

Answer (score 110):

### Mike Grassotti's Minimum Viable Ember.js QuickStart Guide

This quickstart guide should get you from **zero to slightly-more-than-zero** in a couple of minutes. When done, you should feel somewhat confident that ember.js actually works and hopefully will be interested enough to learn more.

*WARNING: Don't just try this guide then think ember-sucks cause "I could write that quickstart-guide better in jQuery or Fortran" or whatever. I am not trying to sell you on ember or anything, this guide is little more than a hello-world.*

#### Step 0 - Check out jsFiddle

[this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/RTK54/) has all the code from this answer

#### Step 1 - Include ember.js and other required libraries

Ember.js requires both jQuery and Handlebars. Be sure those libraries are loaded before ember.js:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0-rc.3/handlebars.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.0.0-rc.1/ember.js"></script>
```

#### Step 2 - Describe your application's user interface using one or more handlebars templates

By default ember will replace body of your html page using content of one or more handlbars templates. Someday these templates will be in separate .hbs files assembled by sprockets or maybe grunt.js. For now we will keep everything in one file and use script tags.

First, let's add a single `application` template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Ember.js is easy?<small> Minimum Viable Ember.js QuickStart Guide</small></h1>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

#### Step 3 - Initialize your ember application

Just add another script block with `App = Ember.Application.create({});` to load ember.js and initialize your application.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  App = Ember.Application.create({});
</script>
```

That's all you need to create a basic ember application, but it's not very interesting.

#### Step 4: Add a controller

Ember evaluates each handlebars templates in the context of a controller. So `application` template has a matching `ApplicationController`. Ember creates is automatically if you don't define one, but here let's customize it to add a message property.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    message: 'This is the application template' 
});
</script>
```

#### Step 5: Define routes + more controllers and templates

Ember router makes it easy to combine templates/controllers into an application.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("index", { path: "/" });
    this.route("list", { path: "/list" });
  });

  App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    message: 'Hello! See how index.hbs is evaluated in the context of IndexController' 
  });

  App.ListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
      controller.set('content', ['angular.js', 'backbone.js', 'ember.js']);
    }
  });

</script>
```

To make this work, we modify our the application template by adding an `{{outlet}}` helper. Ember router will render appropriate template into the outlet depending on user's route. We will also use the `{{linkTo}}` helper to add navigation links.

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
      <div class="container">
          <h1>Ember.js is easy?<small> Minimum Viable Ember.js QuickStart Guide</small></h1>
        <p>{{message}}</p>
        <div class="row">
          {{#linkTo index class="span3 btn btn-large btn-block"}}Home{{/linkTo}}
          {{#linkTo list class="span3 btn btn-large btn-block"}}List{{/linkTo}}
        </div>
        {{outlet}}
      </div>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="list">
      <h3 class="demo-panel-title">This is the list template</h3>
      <ul>
      {{#each item in content}}
          <li>{{item}}</li>
      {{/each}}
       </ul>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
      <h3 class="demo-panel-title">This is the index template</h3>
      <p>{{message}}</p>
    </script>
```

#### Done!

A working example of this application is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/A4hdE/1/embedded/result/).

You can use [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/RTK54/) as a starting point for your own ember apps

#### Next Steps...

- Read the [Ember Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides)
- Maybe buy the [Peepcode](https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs) screencast
- Ask questions here on Stack Overflow or in ember IRC

*For reference, my original answer:*

---

> My question is for any Ember.js expert, and certainly the respective tutorial authors: When should I use design patterns from one tutorial, and when from the other?

These two tutorials represent best practices at the time they were written. For sure there is something that can be learned from each, both are sadly doomed to become out of date because ember.js is moving very quickly. Of the two, Trek's is far more current.

> What components of each are personal preferences, and what components will prove essential as my app matures?
>   If you are developing a new ember application I would not recommend following the Code Lab approach. It is just too out-of-date to be useful.
>
> In Code Lab's design, Ember seems to be closer to existing within the application (even though it is 100% of his custom JS), whereas Trek's application seems to live more within Ember.

Your comment is bang-on. CodeLab is making taking advantage of core ember components and accessing them from global scope. When it was written (9 months ago) this was pretty common but today best-practice for writing ember applications is much closer to what Trek was doing.

That said, even Trek's tutorial is becoming out-of-date. Components that were required `ApplicationView` and `ApplicationController` are now generated by the framework itself.

By far the most current resource is the set of guides published at http://emberjs.com/guides/
- they have been written from the ground up over the last few weeks and reflect the latest (pre-release) version of ember.

I'd also check out trek's wip project here: https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences

**EDIT**:

@sly7_7 : I'd also give an other example, using ember-data https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example

Comment: Toran Billups is doing a good job of keeping up with ember updates on his code camp project: http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2013/01/03/Intro-to-ember-js-and-the-new-router-api/

Comment: I originally wrote the Code Lab as a way to get people ramped up on Ember and MVC frameworks, but unfortunately, I haven't had time to keep it up since, and it sounds like it's changed enough that other folks have created better resources.

Personally, I've since switched to using Angular for most of my projects, I find it requires less JavaScript and is a bit easier to wrap my head around.  Your MVC choice is completely personal, so don't let me sway you.

Comment: Went over to http://emberjs.com/guides and while the explanations were extremely well done, the examples weren't complete enough to be run as-is and suffered from cognitive forward references, which is troublesome for someone coming in completely fresh. Are they still being updated, or is there a complimentary resource?

Comment: For sure they are still being updated. As of today probably the best way to get started quickly is checking out the peepcode screencast at: https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs

Comment: @MikeGrassotti Is there any way you could edit your answer to show source code for getting started with EmberJS? Maybe step by step directions on creating a "Hello World" app with EmberJS?

Comment: Thank you; I just edited out some of the things that don't really belong on the answer (they're meta discussion that won't be relevant in a day or two), otherwise it's a great answer.

Comment: @MikeGrassotti The [tag:Ember.js] tag wiki should be updated to include this question and answer

Comment: @MikeGrassotti You've done a great job in updating your answer (which was already good btw). There are perhaps minor details that can be changed in the code. See http://jsfiddle.net/RTK54/3/ and the comments.

Comment: There is now an updated starter-kit, basically seems to be the same thing you implement here: https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit

Comment: Trek's _"[wip project](https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences)"_ you're linking to is no longer available (the link is broken).

Answer (score 10):

There is 30 minutes fresh screencast made by @tomdale: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ga99hMi7wfY

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) and its accompanying ember generator. Out of the box you get all the tools you need to develop, test and prepare an app for production. As an added bonus, you'll be able to split your view templates into multiple files and start with an intelligent directory structure that will facilitate you in creating a maintainable codebase.

I've written a tutorial on getting it up and running in about 5 minutes. Just install node.js and follow along [here](http://matthewlehner.net/get-started-with-ember-js-in-5-minutes/)

Answer (score 2):

[The Fire Up Ember - Peepcode](https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs) screencast is worth a watch.

Answer (score 1):

Also go through this free tutorial titled [Let’s Learn Ember](http://freecourses.tutsplus.com/lets-learn-ember/) from Tuts+ Premium. Its free because its from their `free courses` series.
This course, as the Tuts guys call it, is divided into fourteen easy to follow chapters.

I hope this helps.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the charcoal yeoman approach.  It gives you a ton of stuff out of the box including:

- a nice folder architecture using a 'module' approach.
- neuter
- live reload
- minify
- uglify
- jshint

and more.

and its super easy to setup, just run `yo charcoal` to create an app then `yo charcoal:module myModule` to add a new module.

more info here: https://github.com/thomasboyt/charcoal

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a Starter Kit, if you would like to use the latest EmberJS with Ember-Data, with Emblem template engine. All wrapped in Middleman, so you can develop with CoffeeScript. Everything on my GitHub: http://goo.gl/a7kz6y

Answer (score 0):

Although outdated [Flame on Ember.js](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/flame-on-a-beginners-guide-to-emberjs.html)
is still a good tutorial for someone looking at ember for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I've started building a series of videos that start from before Ember and build towards using Ember in anger in serious use-cases for real-world things.

If you're interested in seeing this hit the light of day (I'm more than happy to eventually put it public if there's interest) you should definitely go over to the post I made and hit "like" (or just comment here, I guess):

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/making-ember-easier-to-approach-aka-crazy-screencasts-videos-that-will-stick-in-your-mind-for-learning-ember/5284

I'm super keen to make it to help the community flourish, but also to help people learn how to build standard web sites in an easy way.