# Tutorials and Examples on Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, javascript-framework

I am a newbie trying to learn ember but i find the examples on their website too complex and hard to understand? does anyone know a book or web page where i can find good tutorials and in depth about ember.js and handlebar.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $12 you can't beat the peepcode screencast: https://peepcode.com/products/emberjs

UPDATE: See [How to architect an Ember.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204674/how-to-architect-an-ember-js-application/15676487#15676487)

Comment: is it worth it ? i mean did you try it ?

Comment: Kinda, I had peepcode unlimitted plan for a while. Ember changed a lot recently so many of the (very good) free resources have become out of date. this peepcode screencast came out at just the right time and is really well done. i've recommended it to friends, not getting a cut of peepcode sales or anything ;-)

Comment: i saw your tutorial at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204674/how-to-architect-an-ember-js-application)...**Very Useful**

Comment: For much deeper understanding & I found the following ebook(48 pages) very helpful http://www.packtpub.com/create-and-implement-html-templates-using-handlebars-library/book