# How to load an object from an id in an Ember View?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to build a view to display a user card, from their id. So ideally my calling handlebars would look something like:

```
<p>{{view App.UserThumb authorId}}
{{comment}}</p>
```

And then in my UserThumb view, I'd like to be able to load a model, in some sort of setup method or model function, sort of how I'm using controllers:

```
App.UserThumb = Ember.View.extend({
  model: function(view, authorId) {
    User.find(authorId, function(user) { view.set('content', user); } );
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand the 'right' or at least a workable way to do this? Worst case I can go and create the objects first, but I'd like to just keep the id around for a bit first, unless that is just totally at odds with the philosphy of Ember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
{{#each id in listOfIds}}
  {{view App.UserThumb idBinding="id"}}
{{/each}}

App.UserThumb = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var authorId = this.get('id');
    User.find(authorId, function(user) { view.set('content', user); } );
  }
}
```

Only after the view is inserted the `didInsertElement` hook gets executed which gets the required user

Comment: this looks really great - thank you so much. I'm going to wire it in and I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The `model` hook you re using in your View is only available inside a Route. The `model` hook can be used to setup the model for a controller.

See here the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/) for more info on that.

In the spirit of DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself) I'd like to link to this great [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204674/how-to-architect-an-ember-js-application) that will help setup a functional application, the ember way.

Hope it helps

Comment: I've already read that general overview of ember architecture, and it does not answer my question. I'm looking for a way to load item views inside of an each block in my template, where the array is a list of ids, and I want to lazily load the associated data objects after the initial template is rendered.